# Bash parameter expansion inside expect

Tags: expect

What I'm trying to do:

./script 192.168.1.{1..100}

```
#!/bin/expect -f

set servers_ip [lindex $argv 0]
set servers_port [lindex $argv 1]

set timeout -1

foreach ip $servers_ip {
        puts "\nIP = $ip"
}
```

expected output:

```
IP = 192.168.1.1
IP = 192.168.1.2
IP = 192.168.1.3
```

Actual output:

```
IP=192.168.1.1
```

I just can't make the parameter expansion work, and I **CANNOT** use external files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shell has already expanded the brace expansion **before** launching expect.  The first 100 elements of $argv are individual IP addresses.

Here, you want

```
set servers_ip $argv
```

then, iterating over them should give you what you want